# Spring Security's RequestCache expected behaviour?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I was going through the  [Spring Security 6.0.3 documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html#requestcache), as per the **RequestCache** behavior it should redirect me to the saved url before I got authenticated. But when I set the concurrent session **inValidSessionUrl** to "/" it is redirecting me to the "/" address.

What I was expecting this condition should only be invoked if the session has been expired or concurrent session is encountered. But, if I am logging in and going to an endpoint which is secured and saved in **RequestCache** it should directly go to the url as per default behavior.

I think with new  login attempt which is abiding the session management policies I have set, it should  let me continue to the URL saved in  **RequestCache**. Any thoughts?

**NOTE:- if I remove the session management's "inValidSessionUrl" it will work I know that. Secondly, this is my understanding that it should treat the new login session normally.**

```
httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(request ->
        request.requestMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("USER"))
            .requiresChannel(channelRequestMatcherRegistry ->
        channelRequestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers("/secure/**").requiresSecure())
            .formLogin()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement(httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer ->
        httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer.invalidSessionUrl("/")
                .sessionConcurrency(concurrencyControlConfigurer ->
                        concurrencyControlConfigurer.maximumSessions(1)
                                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)))
            .build();
```